# JavaScript SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my confirmation button.
When I click on the button then I still have same link on the top
You can check the codes and you will see that the link should be '`www.website.com?`' but `window.location.href='?'` is not working.

```js
 function myfunction(){ 
  swal({
     title: 'Sweet Alert',
     html: true,
     type: "success",
     showConfirmButton:true,
     preConfirm: function(end) {
    window.location.href='?'
     }
    });
    
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type='button' onclick='myfunction()' value='Sweetalert'>
```

Comment: preConfirm() is not being called. Where does that come from? I do not see it in sweetalert documentation.

Comment: perConfirm is not a function. It's coming with sweetalert cods but I did not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a version of sweetalert that does not have preConfirm, so that function is never executed in your code. 
You need the fork that has preConfirm: https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2
preConfirm also expects a promise to be returned, see example: https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/#ajax-request

```js
function myfunction() {
    swal({
        title: 'Sweet Alert',
        html: true,
        type: "success",
        showConfirmButton: true,
        preConfirm: function (end) {
            $('#test').html('success');
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                resolve();
            });
        }
    });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/5.3.8/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/5.3.8/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type='button' onclick='myfunction()' value='Sweetalert'>
<div id="test"></div>
```